# How to clear a selected text when another select is made?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I want to delete first selected text after another select is made

[Image 1 Before Select Second box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMkNf.png)

[Image 2 Select is made in second box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZgPw.png)

[Image 3 Another Select is made and text is not cleared yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ndQA.png)

**J Query function**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#department').change(function(){
        var department = $(this).val(); 
          //  console.log(department);
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url();?>admin/payroll/fetch_employee",
            method: "POST",
            data: {department_id: department},
            success: function(data)
            {
                    $('#employee').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
 });
</script>
```

**It is how i write for select box**

```
       <div class="form-group" id="border-none">
                    <label for="field-1" class="col-sm-3 control-label"><?= lang('department') ?>
                       <span class="required">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <select name="department" class="form-control select_box" style="width: 100%" id="department">
                            <option value=""><?= lang('select') . ' ' . lang('department') ?></option>                              
                            <?php foreach ($all_department as $row){?>
                            <option <?php if(!empty($allowance_info)){
                                foreach($all_users as $user){
                                    if($row->departments_id==$user->departments_id){ echo 'selected="selected"'; }}
                            }?>value="<?= $row->departments_id?>" ><?= $row->deptname?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" id="border-none">
                    <label for="field-1" class="col-sm-3 control-label"><?= lang('employee') ?>
                       <span class="required">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <select name="employee_id" class="form-control select_box" style="width: 100%" id="employee">
                            <option value=""><?= lang('select') . ' ' . lang('employee') ?></option>       
                            <?php if(!empty($allowance_info)){ ?>
                               <?php foreach ($account as $row){?>
                                <option <?php if( $row->employment_id == $allowance_info->employee_id ){ echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>
                                value="<?= $row->employment_id?>" ><?= $row->fullname ?> 
                                </option>
                            <?php }} ?> 
                        </select>
                     </div>
                </div>
```

**This is my code in controller for fetching employee**

```
public function fetch_employee()
{
    if($this->input->post('department_id'))
    {
        echo $this->payroll_model->fetch_employee($this->input->post('department_id'));
    }
}
```

**This is my code in model retrieving employee data**

```
function fetch_employee($department)
{
    // $this->db->where('departments_id', $department);
    // $this->db->order_by('username', 'ASC');
    // $query = $this->db->get('tbl_users');

    $this->db->select('tbl_account_details.*', FALSE);
    $this->db->select('tbl_users.*',FALSE);
    $this->db->from('tbl_account_details');
    $this->db->join('tbl_users','tbl_users.user_id=tbl_account_details.user_id','left');
    $this->db->where('tbl_users.departments_id', $department);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    $output = '<option value="">Select Employee</option>';
    foreach($query->result() as $row)
    {
        $output .= '<option value="'.$row->employment_id.'">'.$row->fullname.'</option>';
    }
    return $output;

}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *within the question itself*. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also note that both the images are identical.

Comment: Add HTML code also in question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming one `<select>` tag has id `department` and other `<select>` has `employee`

Here on changing in department dropdown, an employee dropdown is resetting

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#department').change(function(){
        var department = $(this).val(); 
        $('#employee').html('<option value="">Select Employee</option>'); //Resetting employee dropdown here

        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url();?>admin/payroll/fetch_employee",
            method: "POST",
            data: {department_id: department},
            success: function(data)
            {
               $('#employee').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
 });
</script>
```

HTML should be like this

```
<select id="employee">
  <option value=''>Select Employee</option>
  <option value='Jhon'>Jhon</option>
  <option value='Smith'>Smith</option>
  <option value='Elia'>Elia</option>
</select>

<select id="department">
  <option value=''>Select Department</option>
  <option value='IT'>IT</option>
  <option value='HR'>HR</option>
  <option value='Accounts'>Accounts</option>
</select>
```

See live demo on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bfhx2j9s/1/)

Comment: @Kelly dropdowns have same ids that I've mentioned above?

Comment: Yes bro they are the same

Comment: Do you want to show employee list of the specific department on department change?

Comment: yes ... and employee is chosen and as soon as department is chose again i don't want to show first employee text in the box ....

Comment: i want to clear select box text when another select is made

Comment: Got your point. I want to clear one more thing that is on changing department dropdown list of employees populating in the employee dropdown?

Comment: @Kelly I've made changes in the JQuery part of the answer. Hope it will help you.

Comment: all employees are disappeared if i write like above

Comment: @Kelly on everytime change in department new employee list will populate. So, it is necessary to empty employee dropdown list fist for new record

Comment: for first time change all employee should not be disappeared

Comment: Then you have to make a condition when to run ajax request

Comment: Thanks so much for your help bro